# How to prevent "aspxerrorpath" from page using Azure

Tags: azure, web-config

i have a website **"www.oldwebsite.com"** at Microsoft Azure.
At first if someone try to enter in url **"www.oldwebite.com/explorer/9:53"** it goes to some page. Now i have transfer my website to **"web.oldwebsite.com"**. 
i want to redirect my **www.oldwebite.com/explorer/9:53** (this page does not exist since i have transfer my website to web application) to **www.web.oldwebsite.com/explorer/9:53**
i have configured my web.config file :

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="http://web.oldwebsite.com/"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now if i run this it show this http://web.oldwebsite.com/?aspxerrorpath=/explorer/9:53 in URL and then goes to **web.oldwebsite.com**

I want it to go to  http://web.oldwebsite.com/explorer/9:53

Please Help!!

Comment: MS Azure adds this 'aspxerrorpath' to the url when redirected. This is undesirable behavior for many, myself included.